# Click on dom item and send reference of it to the typescript controller

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following piece of html template for my component :

```
 <li *ngFor="let document of displayedDocuments; let index = index"  (click)="openPreviewModal(document, $event)">
    <ng-container *ngIf="!isPreviewHidden; else placeholder">
      <img *ngIf="!isPreviewHidden" ...
```

When I click any list-item I want to open a modal specific to that list item, but I need to access the src of the img inside the list-item, so that's why I passed $event to the openPreviewModal function, but it comes undefined.

Is there any way to achieve the needed result?

Comment: If your object's structure is such that you have `document.imgSrc` (or however you have your src named) pass that.

Comment: Also, your ng-container already checks for !isPreviewHidden, so no need to check it again in img tag